# Glare node with Fog glow makes Hard Edges

Tags: compositing-nodes, glare

When I use the Fog Glow node, there are two Parts on my Character that makes Hard Edges.
Why is that so and how can I fix it?
Some more details to the scene There is nothing big just 3 area light with low value And the glare node is on mix 0, threshold 1 and size 7.
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the lighting conditions and the settings of your Glare node.

Comment: Looks more like a light source reflection than Glare effect ...

Comment: no it is the glare node, when I mute the glare node than its gone

Comment: Maybe we need the file to check it. A hard edge usually comes from the fact that something is just a little brigther than the threshold, because the glow itself falls off a lot compared to the bright surface. Let's say threshold is 1, the bright area is 1.1, then there's only a difference of 0.1 contributing to the glow which is not much. If the bright area would be 10, there would be much more and brighter glow so that the edge wouldn't look that hard. Have you tried setting the Mix to 1 to see how the glow itself looks? You could blur it and add it onto the oringinal image.

Comment: Yeah that should be the problem but I don't want to change the light so what exactly do you mean with blur it and add it?

Comment: Could you maybe show an example for what you mean

Comment: @3Dbob I always prefer using the glow separately from the original image. So if you set the Mix value of the Glare node to 1 instead of 0, the output will give you just the glow effect without the original image mixed in. So plug the original image in the first input of a MixRGB node and the glow in the second. Set the node to Add. This way you can add the glow with more control and even more intensity if you set the factor to > 1. And before adding you could blur the glow with a Blur node.

Comment: If you want to let us inspect ... append all light and character's material into a new blend, assign material to a sphere placed in location of character and share via https://blend-exchange.com/ thanks

Comment: I've fixed now with the cryptomatte node. I mask the character out of the glow